# deis builder keep restart with liveness probe fail

Tags: kubernetes, deis

I tried to delete the pods, or rescale the replicas, or delete the aws instances, but still cannot make the deis builder work normally. It keeps restart with failed liveness probe. Below the logs from the deis builder

```
$ kubectl describe pods/deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg -n deis
Name:       deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg
    Namespace:  deis
    Node:       ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal/10.0.48.189
    Start Time: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 22:29:03 -0400
    Labels:     app=deis-builder
            pod-template-hash=2995120344
    Status:     Running
    IP:     10.34.184.7
    Controllers:    ReplicaSet/deis-builder-2995120344
    Containers:
      deis-builder:
        Container ID:   docker://f2b7799712c347759832270716057b6ac3be68298eef3057c25727b66024c84a
        Image:      quay.io/deis/builder:v2.7.1
        Image ID:       docker-pullable://quay.io/deis/builder@sha256:3dab1dd4e6359d1588fee1b4f93ef9f5c70f268f17de5bed4bc13faa210ce5d0
        Ports:      2223/TCP, 8092/TCP
        State:      Waiting
          Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
        Last State:     Terminated
          Reason:       Error
          Exit Code:    2
          Started:      Wed, 15 Mar 2017 22:37:37 -0400
          Finished:     Wed, 15 Mar 2017 22:38:15 -0400
        Ready:      False
        Restart Count:  7
        Liveness:       http-get http://:8092/healthz delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
        Readiness:      http-get http://:8092/readiness delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
        Volume Mounts:
          /var/run/secrets/api/auth from builder-key-auth (ro)
          /var/run/secrets/deis/builder/ssh from builder-ssh-private-keys (ro)
          /var/run/secrets/deis/objectstore/creds from objectstore-creds (ro)
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from deis-builder-token-qbqff (ro)
        Environment Variables:
          DEIS_REGISTRY_SERVICE_HOST:   127.0.0.1
          DEIS_REGISTRY_SERVICE_PORT:   5555
          HEALTH_SERVER_PORT:       8092
          EXTERNAL_PORT:            2223
          BUILDER_STORAGE:          s3
          DEIS_REGISTRY_LOCATION:       ecr
          DEIS_REGISTRY_SECRET_PREFIX:  private-registry
          GIT_LOCK_TIMEOUT:         10
          SLUGBUILDER_IMAGE_NAME:       <set to the key 'image' of config map 'slugbuilder-config'>
          SLUG_BUILDER_IMAGE_PULL_POLICY:   <set to the key 'pullpolicy' of config map 'slugbuilder-config'>
          DOCKERBUILDER_IMAGE_NAME:     <set to the key 'image' of config map 'dockerbuilder-config'>
          DOCKER_BUILDER_IMAGE_PULL_POLICY: <set to the key 'pullpolicy' of config map 'dockerbuilder-config'>
          DOCKERIMAGE:          1
          DEIS_DEBUG:           false
          POD_NAMESPACE:            deis (v1:metadata.namespace)
          DEIS_BUILDER_KEY:         <set to the key 'builder-key' in secret 'builder-key-auth'>
    Conditions:
      Type      Status
      Initialized   True
      Ready     False
      PodScheduled  True
    Volumes:
      builder-key-auth:
        Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
        SecretName: builder-key-auth
      builder-ssh-private-keys:
        Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
        SecretName: builder-ssh-private-keys
      objectstore-creds:
        Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
        SecretName: objectstorage-keyfile
      deis-builder-token-qbqff:
        Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
        SecretName: deis-builder-token-qbqff
    QoS Class:  BestEffort
    Tolerations:    <none>
    Events:
      FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                    SubObjectPath           Type        ReasonMessage
      --------- --------    -----   ----                    -------------           --------    -------------
      10m       10m     1   {default-scheduler }                            Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg to ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal
      10m       10m     1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      StartedStarted container with docker id 7eac3a357f61
      10m       10m     1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      CreatedCreated container with docker id 7eac3a357f61; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
      9m        9m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      CreatedCreated container with docker id 8e730f2731ef; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
      9m        9m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      StartedStarted container with docker id 8e730f2731ef
      9m        9m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      KillingKilling container with docker id 7eac3a357f61: pod "deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)" container "deis-builder" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
      9m        9m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      CreatedCreated container with docker id 5f4e695c595a; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
      9m        9m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      KillingKilling container with docker id 8e730f2731ef: pod "deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)" container "deis-builder" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
      9m        9m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      StartedStarted container with docker id 5f4e695c595a
      8m        8m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      CreatedCreated container with docker id c87d762fc118; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
      8m        8m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      StartedStarted container with docker id c87d762fc118
      8m        8m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      KillingKilling container with docker id 5f4e695c595a: pod "deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)" container "deis-builder" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
      7m        7m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      CreatedCreated container with docker id 416573d43fe4; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
      7m        7m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      StartedStarted container with docker id 416573d43fe4
      7m        7m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      KillingKilling container with docker id c87d762fc118: pod "deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)" container "deis-builder" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
      7m        7m      1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal      KillingKilling container with docker id 416573d43fe4: pod "deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)" container "deis-builder" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
      7m        6m      4   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}                   Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "deis-builder" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=deis-builder pod=deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)"

      6m    6m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Created     Created container with docker id bf5b29729c27; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
      6m    6m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Started     Started container with docker id bf5b29729c27
      9m    5m  4   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Warning Unhealthy   Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.34.184.7:8092/readiness: dial tcp 10.34.184.7:8092: getsockopt: connection refused
      9m    5m  4   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Warning Unhealthy   Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.34.184.7:8092/healthz: dial tcp 10.34.184.7:8092: getsockopt: connection refused
      5m    5m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Started     Started container with docker id e457328db858
      5m    5m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Created     Created container with docker id e457328db858; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
      5m    5m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Killing     Killing container with docker id bf5b29729c27: pod "deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)" container "deis-builder" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
      5m    5m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Killing     Killing container with docker id e457328db858: pod "deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)" container "deis-builder" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
      5m    2m  13  {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}                   Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "deis-builder" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 2m40s restarting failed container=deis-builder pod=deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)"

      2m    2m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Started     Started container with docker id f2b7799712c3
      10m   2m  8   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Pulled      Container image "quay.io/deis/builder:v2.7.1" already present on machine
      2m    2m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Created     Created container with docker id f2b7799712c3; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
      10m   1m  6   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Warning Unhealthy   Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.34.184.7:8092/healthz: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
      1m    1m  1   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Normal  Killing     Killing container with docker id f2b7799712c3: pod "deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)" container "deis-builder" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
      7m    9s  26  {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}   spec.containers{deis-builder}   Warning BackOff     Back-off restarting failed docker container
      1m    9s  9   {kubelet ip-10-0-48-189.ec2.internal}                   Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "deis-builder" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=deis-builder pod=deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg_deis(52027ebf-09f0-11e7-8bbf-0a73a2cd36e4)"
```

Comment: That's unreadable. Please look into how to format things on StackOverflow so it's easier for people to help you, since you want people to help you.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed the messy display.

Answer (score 0):

What does helm ls show for the workflow version of deis?

Anything showing up in output for the logs for the container when you run the command below?

kubectl --namespace deis logs deis-builder-2995120344-mz2zg

That logs bit will help with anyone trying to help you figure out your unhealthy builder.

Comment: The version is v2.2.2. Also I edited the log to make it readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete deis and redeploy it.